# Looking for Spring MVC auto build and auto deploy on any change in JSP, js or JAVA files

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, jsp, jboss

I have a web project on Spring MVC + Maven + Jboss. Whenever I do some changes in controller or view I need to rebuild and redeploy the project which is very time-consuming.

e.g => If I just want to change the padding or margin and for changes to be implemented I need to rebuild and redeploy the project

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:
Spring devtools or JRebel